# How To Add Animated Loading GIF For This jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have this following code on my site :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.notif-email > a').click(function(e) {
            $("#email-notif").load("notif-email.php");
      });
      $('.notif-message > a').click(function(e) {
            $("#message-notif").load("notif-message.php");
      });
      $('.notif-prospect > a').click(function(e) {
            $("#prospect-notif").load("notif-prospect.php");
      });
  });
</script>
```

and I want to add some loading effect with GIF animated file, let's say... loading.gif and I want to show it to user after they 'Click' something but still waiting for load() file to be executed on the server.

how to do that?

UPDATE :

here's more code associates with that jQuery script :

```
<li class="notif-email"><a href="#" title="17 new emails">View New Emails</a>
<div class="popup-notif">
<div class="notif-top">
<div class="notif-title">Notifications</div>
</div><!-- .notif-top -->
<div class="notif-body">
<div id="email-notif" class="notif-child-wrap">
</div><!-- .notif-child-wrap -->
</div><!-- .notif-body -->
</div><!-- .popup-notif -->
</li>

<li class="notif-message"><a href="#" title="5 new messages">View New Messages</a>
<div class="popup-notif">
<div class="notif-top">
<div class="notif-title">Messages</div>
</div><!-- .notif-top -->
<div class="notif-body">
<div id="message-notif" class="notif-child-wrap">    
</div><!-- .notif-child-wrap -->
</div><!-- .notif-body -->
</div><!-- .popup-notif -->
</li>

<li class="notif-prospect"><a href="#" title="1,999 new prospects">View New Prospects</a>
<div class="popup-notif">
<div class="notif-top">
<div class="notif-title">New Prospects</div>
</div><!-- .notif-top -->
<div class="notif-body">
<div id="prospect-notif" class="notif-child-wrap">    
</div><!-- .notif-child-wrap -->
</div><!-- .notif-body -->
</div><!-- .popup-notif -->
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function togglemask(show) {
  if(show)
   $('#target').append('<img class="loadergif" src="loading.gif" width="" height="">');
  else
   $('#target').remove('img.loadergif');
}

$(document).ready(function(){
      $('.notif-email > a').click(function(e) {
            togglemask(true);
            $("#email-notif").load("notif-email.php", togglemask(false));
      });
      $('.notif-message > a').click(function(e) {
            togglemask(true);
            $("#message-notif").load("notif-message.php", togglemask(false));
      });
      $('.notif-prospect > a').click(function(e) {
            togglemask(true);
            $("#prospect-notif").load("notif-prospect.php", togglemask(false));
      });
  });
```

#### Note

Here `#target` is just for example. you can use any element to add that.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but why you put #target (id=target)? do I have to add <div id="target"> on where I want to put the animated gif?

Comment: @RobertHanson Here `#target` is just for example. you can use any element to add that.

Comment: I just update my post, please check it out. do I have to add #target on my HTML part?

Comment: what this function actually does : togglemask ? is it built-in function of jQuery? I don't think so.. shouldn't you declare it first before you can use it?

Answer (score 0):

load accepts a second argument, which is complete event handler, what I do is show the gif before calling and hide it using the function:

gif.show();
$("#...").load("...", function(){ gif.hide(); });

we wrap it in a single call, so it looks like:

$("#...").loadWithProgress({url: "...", before: function(){ /* show the gif*/ }, after: function(){ /* hide gif*/ }});